# Naming ng-show dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of users and when I click on a list item I would like a sub section to slide down from beneath it. I'm fine with the animation and this isn't the area I need help on. My problem is that when I click on any list item, all drop-down sections appear underneath all list items.

So my approach now is to use the `id` of each user to create a unique `ng-show`. Then when I click on a list item a function is called:

```
<ul id="users" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <li ng-click="showUserDetail(user.id)">
        {{user.name}}
        <div class="slide" ng-show="dropDownSection_{{user.id}}">
            //Stuff will go here
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `showUserDetail` function is:

```
$scope.showUserDetail = function(id) {
    //not sure I can do this?
    var section = "dropDownSection" + "_" + id;
    $scope.section = true; //this would normally show the animation
}
```

but this doesn't work - the dropdown doesn't appear.

Is there a nice "Angular" way of achieving something like this?

Comment: Currently it obviously doesn't appear because you don't set the value of `dropDownSection_...` anywhere, hence it is evaluated as `false`.

Comment: sorry that's a typo. I changed the code for the question and missed that bit. I will update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you can do is.. set the id to show on ng-click and check that id in ng-show

`ng-click="idToDisplay = user.id"`

and

`ng-show="idToDisplay == user.id"`

Comment: I wasn't aware the idea behind SO was to answer as quick as possible ;) I just took my time adding a Plunker, which is why I posted my answer with very similar content after yours.

Comment: Actually it makes some funny, what is the difference between ng-show="userDetailId == user.id" and ng-show="true" ?

Comment: You are absolutely right and I'm fine with you getting the accepted answer. I just didn't like your complaint about you being first, since I started creating my answer before yours was posted. But no worries, everything good now! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of the user for which details are currently shown via a variable on the scope. You set this variable when you click on a user.

```
$scope.userDetailId = 0; 
$scope.showUserDetail = function (id) {
    $scope.userDetailId = id;
}
```

Then, inside your `ng-repeat` section, you can check if the current user's id matches the tracked ID:

```
<ul id="users" ng-repeat="user in users">
  <li ng-click="showUserDetail(user.id)">
    {{user.name}}
    <div class="slide" ng-show="userDetailId == user.id">
      //Stuff will go here
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Check this [Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/jhjwzgth/1/) for a demo.

Comment: That's a nice idea - going to try it now.

Comment: Actually it makes some funny,  what is the difference between `ng-show="userDetailId == user.id"` and `ng-show="true"` ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran `user.id` is different in every iteration of the `ng-repeat`, while `userDetailId` stays the same. Check the Plunker, this works fine.

Comment: Where is the OP told `userDetailId` is static id?

Comment: And also the OP question is `Naming ng-show dynamically` but your answer is totally not matched for him question. i think OP was confused :(

Comment: `userDetailId` is a variable I introduced to keep track of the user for which details are currently shown. It is set when a user is clicked on in the list.

Comment: Why you   introduced to keep track of the user? where is he asking for this? don't confuse me. 

.
actually the question is `How to create dynamically ng-show object`? But the answer is a mismatched solution. any way best of luck :p

Comment: My answer achieves exactly the same thing as the accepted answer, just using a slightly different method by moving some of the logic into the controller.